# CGFloat to $ST4 Swift Build Error

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit, swift

Just working on the UIKit / CoreGraphics stuff in Swift and I keep coming across this error - "Cannot convert CGFloat to type ST$4" in the line with atan2f().

```
    var location : CGPoint = recogniser.locationInView(spinnerImage)

    var spinnerXCentre = spinnerImage.center.x
    var spinnerYCentre = spinnerImage.center.y

    var dx = location.x - spinnerXCentre
    var dy = location.y - spinnerYCentre

    var a  = atan2f(dx, dy)
```

As far as I can see, I think dx and dy will be doubles and I've tried down-casting them to floats to no avail. Then, if I change that line to:

```
var a  = atan2f(dx, (-1 * dy))
```

Then I get a different error stating 'no overload for operator * that accepts the supplied arguments" - I'm definitely missing something here, anyone care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Adventure-Swift/Listings/Adventure_Adventure_Shared_Utilities_GraphicsUtilities_swift.html

```
#if arch(arm) || arch(i386)
func sin(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return sinf(x)
}

func cos(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return cosf(x)
}
func hypot(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return hypotf(x, y)
}

func atan2(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return atan2f(x, y)
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`dx` and `dy` have type `CGFloat` which is `Float` on the 32-bit architecture and
`Double` on the 64-bit architecture. `atan2f()` on the other hand, takes `Float`
arguments.

Swift does not implicitly convert types, therefore you have to add explicit casts.
In this case you should convert everything to `Double` and use `atan2` instead
of `atan2f()`, so that you get the maximum possible precision on 64-bit.

```
var a  = atan2(Double(dx), Double(dy))
var b  = atan2(Double(dx), -1.0 * Double(dy))
```

Alternatively, you can declare `dx`, `dy` to be of type `Double`, in that case the 
conversion is done during the assignment:

```
var dx : Double = location.x - spinnerXCentre
var dy : Double = location.y - spinnerYCentre
var a  = atan2(dx, dy)
```

Note that the first argument of `atan2()` is the *y-component*, so you probably want

```
var a  = atan2(Double(dy), Double(dx))
```